# Solved-NotFittedError: This SVC instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, crop, sklearn-pandas

*(Newbie)*
I am trying to train and predict soil-based crop suggestions with linear regressions. While doing that, I faced this traceback, mentioned above. Let me know if I need to add more information. Could it be scikit's version-related problems?

Codes-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn import metrics 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif, RFE
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
```

Training, test sets with X and y-

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=.33)
```

To avoid bias, I applied the scaling after splitting data into training and test-

```
mmscaler = MinMaxScaler() 
X_train = mmscaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = mmscaler.transform(X_test)
# convert labels to numerical values 
y_train = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(np.asarray(y_train).ravel())
y_test = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(np.asarray(y_test).ravel())
```

Working with scikit-learn, **for the first time-**

```
model = RandomForestClassifier()

model.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
```

To get the model with higher accuracy-

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_pred,y_test),square=True,cmap='Blues_r',annot=True,fmt=".0f",linewidths=.5)
ax = plt.gca()
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(crop_names,rotation='vertical')
_ = ax.set_yticklabels(crop_names,rotation='horizontal')
plt.tight_layout()

def get_predictions(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7):
    feature = mmscaler.transform(np.asarray([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7]).reshape((1,-1)))
    croptoplant = crop_names[model.predict(feature).item()]
    print('{} should grow very well under these conditions'.format(croptoplant.upper()))
```

After running these widget sliders, I am getting the problem-

```
N = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.0, max=140.0, value=25.0, step=2.5, description="Nitrogen")
P = widgets.FloatSlider(min=5.0, max=145.0, value=25.0, step=2.5, description="Phosphorus")
K = widgets.FloatSlider(min=5.0, max=205.0, value=25.0, step=2.5, description="Potassium")
temp = widgets.FloatSlider(min=10.0, max=44.0, value=25.0, step=2.5, description="Temperature")
hum = widgets.FloatSlider(min=15.0, max=99.0, value=25.0, step=2.5, description="humidity")
ph = widgets.FloatSlider(min=3.5, max=9.9, value=5.0, step=.5, description="pH")
rain = widgets.FloatSlider(min=20.0, max=298.0, value=25.0, step=2.5, description="Rainfall (mm)")
    
im = widgets.interact_manual(get_predictions,x1=N,x2=P,x3=K,x4=temp,x5=hum,x6=ph,x7=rain)
_ = im.widget.children[-2].description = 'Find Suitable Crops'
_ = im.widget.children[-2].style.button_color='lightgreen'

display(im)
```

**The error**-

```
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/interaction.py in update(self, *args)
    255                     value = widget.get_interact_value()
    256                     self.kwargs[widget._kwarg] = value
--> 257                 self.result = self.f(**self.kwargs)
    258                 show_inline_matplotlib_plots()
    259                 if self.auto_display and self.result is not None:

2 frames
<ipython-input-21-2d4402e5f995> in get_predictions(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
      1 def get_predictions(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7):
      2     feature = mmscaler.transform(np.asarray([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7]).reshape((1,-1)))
----> 3     croptoplant = crop_names[model.predict(feature).item()]
      4     print('{} should grow very well under these conditions'.format(croptoplant.upper()))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py in predict(self, X)
    776             Class labels for samples in X.
    777         """
--> 778         check_is_fitted(self)
    779         if self.break_ties and self.decision_function_shape == "ovo":
    780             raise ValueError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
   1220 
   1221     if not fitted:
-> 1222         raise NotFittedError(msg % {"name": type(estimator).__name__})
   1223 
   1224 

NotFittedError: This SVC instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Comment: Is this running in a `jupyter` notebook?  If so, if you restart the kernel and run all the cells from the beginning, does the same error appear?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, yes, on Colab. I inserted-

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)

```
before denoting the widgets and made the scikit metrics run again to predict. It solved the issue.

Comment: Glad it's solved.  I think notebooks are awesome, but I do still need to keep in mind that the current state of the variables, etc., isn't necessarily apparent, nor a result of, the code from top down. During development and debugging I often run cells "out of order". If run-time isn't too long, and sometimes when it is, I restart the kernel and run all the cells from top to bottom.

Comment: I was unable to understand the issue. I did what you suggested repeatedly but the error kept showing up. Then, I thought about running the confusion matrix, again, for the widgets. Then, it worked! It is baffling me! I did do an abrupt thing without a solid ground but it worked. I do not know how it worked but it did. I am not satisfied myself with my own answer.

Comment: Without your `X` and `y` it would be difficult for me to reproduce your issue.  IDK if it's a scoping issue or perhaps some `jupyter`/`widgets` quirk.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but I couldn't do it.  Here's a [Binder.org JupyterLab notebook](https://gesis.mybinder.org/binder/v2/gh/rickhg12hs/Binder/073ff44512cecf0e09c7e77640dc7b05868d3a2f?urlpath=lab%2Ftree%2Firis_MLPClass_interact.ipynb) where I do predictions with `interact`.

Comment: There is an inconsistent problem with it. I again removed the line to import the confusion matrix and ran it, the problem occurred. It seems that I have to importing the conf matrix before the widgets. Why is it happening? I already imported it. I have another issue with a tensor flow based workflow. I will notify you about it, @rickhg12hs, soon.